# PostgreSQL использование цикла FOR

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

В таблице документов есть поля, которsе нужно обновить. Чтоб не обновлять каждую строку отдельно попробовал написать функцию:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updateTable

BEGIN
    FOR i in 3..10 LOOP
        update card_doc set first_executant = (select array_to_string(array(select ed.name_person from exec_doc ed, card_doc cd where cd.reg_ind_doc = 'i/1' and ed.id_card_doc_fk = cd.id_card_doc and cd.id_period_cardf_fk = 30 and cd.sign = 0), ', ')) where reg_ind_doc = 'i/1' and id_period_cardf_fk = 30;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Но при запуске видает ошибку:

```
ERROR:  ОШИБКА:  ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "FOR")
LINE 4:   FOR i in 3..10 LOOP
          ^
SQL-состояние: 42601
Символ: 45
```

Comment: [CREATE FUNCTION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html). Где `RETURNS`? Где `AS`? Где открывающие `$$`?